# php - how to sort an array with values like "+1", "-20"

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a PHP script with an array like this:

```
array (

"+15" => 5,
"-5" => 20,
"+2" => 2,
"-1" => 9

)
```

The keys are all unique (the +15 etc). I want to sort by the keys so this:

```
foreach($array as $k => $v ) {

echo $k . ' has a count of ' . $v;

}
```

any ideas on sorting by the keys with + and -'s. I can't get that working correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would [natsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) work?

From php.net:

```
<?
    $array1 = $array2 = array("img12.png", "img10.png", "img2.png", "img1.png");

    asort($array1);
    echo "Standard sorting\n";
    print_r($array1);

    natsort($array2);
    echo "\nNatural order sorting\n";
    print_r($array2);
?>
```

Output:

```
Standard sorting
Array
(
    [3] => img1.png
    [1] => img10.png
    [0] => img12.png
    [2] => img2.png
)

Natural order sorting
Array
(
    [3] => img1.png
    [2] => img2.png
    [1] => img10.png
    [0] => img12.png
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `ksort`, (your keys are all numeric strings, they will be treated as integers.)

```
ksort($array);
var_dump($array);
```

Result:

```
array(4) {
  [-5]=>
  int(20)
  [-1]=>
  int(9)
  ["+2"]=>
  int(2)
  ["+15"]=>
  int(5)
}
```

Comment: used `uksort( $array, 'intval');` but first in $array i used the `-` sign for negative numbers but no `+` plus sign for positive numbers and it worked fine. thanks